# Perfect number generator from a given min and max value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input, numbers

I wanted to make a perfect number generator where it would take a min and max value and then print out all the perfect numbers between the min and max value.
Please help me
My code:

```
  min_value=int(input("Enter a min value: "))
max_value=int(input("Enter a max value: "))
factors=[] # factors list
for x in range(min_value,max_value): # initiliazing the numbers
    for i in range(min_value,max_value): # adding all the factors to the factor list
        if x%i==0: # checking if its a factor or not
            factors.append(i) #appending the factor
    sum=0 # initilazing the sum
    for num in range(len(factors)): # creating an indice to initialize sum of factors
        sum=sum+factors[num] # adding the value of sum
    if sum==x: # checking if the sum value is equal to a number
        print(x) # printing the number
```

I have added the comments.
Thanks in advance!
Edit: Perfect numbers are those numbers whose factors add up to itself. For eg. 6. 6 factors are: 1,2,3. 1+2+3=6

Comment: Perfect numbers are those numbers whose factors add up to itself. For eg. 6. 6 factors are: 1,2,3. 1+2+3=6. Adding this to the post

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing that:

```py
min_value = int(input('Min value: '))
max_value = int(input('Max value: '))

result = []
for number in range(min_value, max_value + 1):
    temp_list = []
    for num in range(1, number // 2 + 1):
        if number % num == 0:
            temp_list.append(num)
    if sum(temp_list) == number:
        result.append(number)

print(result)
```

This again asks for user to input the min value and max value and then it loops over that range

and for every number in the range it loops over all the factors of it and appends them to the list, then using sum it calculates the sum of all items in the list and checks if they equal to number, if they do append the number to list

Answer (score 0):

Just find factor first then do their `summation` if this satisfies perfect-number `definition` then `append` then in new list `ls`

```
min_value=int(input("Enter a min value: "))
max_value=int(input("Enter a max value: "))

def factor_sum(x):
    factors = []
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        if x % i == 0:
            if x != i:
                factors.append(i)
    return factors

ls = []
for x in range(min_value,max_value):
    sum_ = sum(factor_sum(x))
    if x == sum_:
        ls.append(x)
    
print(ls)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i would be in [1, x-1] but not [min_value, max_value].For example,
if max_value = 100 and min_value = 1.I know 28 is a prefect number.We can make x = 28.So it is obvious that i's range should be [1, 27]

```
# for i in range(min_value,max_value): 
for i in range(0, x)
```